# Conjugation of regular subgroups in the holomorph

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, holomorph

Given a finite group $G$, denote by $Hol(G)$ its holomorph and by $S(G)$ its group of permutations. It is well known that for regular subgroups $N,M\le Hol(G)$, being isomorphic or being conjugate are two equivalent data. Assume that this holds, i.e. let $M,N\le Hol(G)$ regular such that $\sigma^{-1}N\sigma=M$ for some $\sigma\in S(G)$. Being $N,M$ in the holomorph, is it restrictive to assume that such $\sigma\in Aut(G)$?

Comment: Do you want to allow that $\sigma$ is not a homomorphism? For example, take $N=M$ and $\sigma$ a permuation that fixes $N$ but does not fix the identity.

Comment: And what exactly does "restrictive" mean in this context? It sounds a bit like "without loss of generality", which is only meaningful in the context of a proof.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I answer both. I am asking if once taken two conjugate regular subgroups of the holomorph, we can prove that the permutation that conjugates one to the other is, in fact, an automorphism, or if it is false in general., and we can exhibit an example of a pair of regular subgroups of the holomorph which are conjugate by a permutation which is not a homomorphism. In particular, I am interested when G is cyclic of prime power order.

Comment: or, at least, if that there exists always one automorphism taking $M$ to $N$ when they are conjugate.

Comment: Let me add to ahulpke's precise answer that these regular subgroups will give you skew braces with additive group G, and the skew braces you find are isomorphic if and only if you can find $\sigma$ which is an automorphisms of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure about the formulation of the question, but the following is probably a counterexample: The holomorph of $C_9$ can be generated by the normal subgroup  $N=\langle  (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)\rangle\cong C_9$ and the group $U=\langle  (2,3,5,9,8,6)(4,7)\rangle$ that acts as the full automorphism group of $N$.
Also in the holomorph is the regular subgroup $M=\langle (1,2,6,4,5,9,7,8,3)\rangle$, also isomorphic to $C_9$. As isomorphic regular groups, $N$ and $M$ are conjugate in $S_9$ (namely by $\sigma=(3,6,9)$), but they are not conjugate in the holomorph, and $\sigma$ does not normalize $N$ (and thus cannot induce an automorphism of $N$).